# Moving all but some directories and files to another using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that says:

*Move every single file and folder except: .gitignore, .git. Then Prompt on Documentation folder (Would you like the documentation folder for this package?), if no - don't move, if yes, move.*

I have no idea what I'm doing as I am NEW to bash scripting, and all I have so far is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

if [ -d "vender/adamb.balan/aisis-core/" ]
  // do soemthing
fi
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
     #!/bin/bash
     echo Do you want to move (Y/N) ?
     read resp
     echo "$resp"
     if [ [ $resp = 'y' ] || [ $resp = 'Y'] ]; then  
        mv <source dir name>/* <destination dir name>/ 
     fi
```

Comment: Did you try it? `bash: [: =: unary operator expected`

Comment: Either use `[[ $resp = 'y' || $resp = 'Y' ]]` or `[ ... ] || [ ... ]`. Single brackets are not syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
 read resp
 if [ $resp = 'y' -o $resp = 'Y' ]; then  
    # do your mv.
 fi
```

But it is apparently deprecated... http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression

Comment: `-o` is deprecated; use `[ $resp = 'y' ] || [ $resp = 'Y' ]` instead.

Comment: @chepner didn't know. do you know why it is deprecated?

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, under "Application Usage". Basically, there are problems with things like `test "$a" -a "$b"` for some values of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

source_folder=$1       
project=$2
dest_folder=$3

if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]; then
    echo "$0 source_folder project dest_folder"
    echo "------------------------------------"
    echo "$0 /home/projects project1 /var/tmp"
    echo "This will cd into /home/projects tar up required from folder project1"
    echo "and extract to a folder called project1 folder in /var/tmp"
    exit 1;
fi


echo "Do you want to move Documents (Y/N) ?"
read resp
addon=" --exclude=.git --exclude=.gitignore "
if [ $resp == 'n' ] || [ $resp == 'n' ]; then     
    addon=$addon"--exclude=Documents"
fi
(cd $source_folder; tar -cvzf $addon - $project) | (cd $dest_folder; tar -xvzf -)
# remove folder when and if you are happy with the dest_folders $project content
# rm -rf $source_folder/$project
```

You could try something like above

Rather than moving it is taring it up and extracting it at the same time to a new destination folder 
You can then rm -rf $source (when your happy it all works as required)

Comment: I suspect it will need 3 variables sourcefolder source and destfolder. If you do add the variable at the top replace to cd $ sourcefolder;tar -cvzf $addon - $ source